# Find ACEs by SecurityIdentity instead of ObjectIdentity

Tags: symfony, acl

The Symfony2 ACL makes it relatively easy to search for ACE records by `ObjectIdentity`, optionally filtered by `SecurityIdentity`.

However, I need the reverse:  I need to fetch all ACEs for a given `SecurityIdentity`, optionally filtered by `ObjectIdentity`.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I ultimately came up with.

It has some significant limitations:

- It naïvely assumes that any ACEs it finds grant access.
- It only matches against a single User and ignores any access granted to that User's roles.
- It does not support filtering by mask (not strictly necessary, but would be very helpful).

Also note that this method returns **ObjectIdentities**, not **ACEs**.  Technically, this is not what I requested in my OP, but it's close enough that I figured I'd post it anyway.

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authorization\Acl;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Dbal\MutableAclProvider;

class AclProvider
    extends MutableAclProvider
{
    /** @var Connection */
    protected $connection;

    /** Locates all objects that the specified User has access to.
     *
     * Note that this method has a few limitations:
     *  - No support for filtering by mask.
     *  - No support for ACEs that match one of the User's roles (only ACEs that
     *      reference the User's security identity will be matched).
     *  - Every ACE that matches is assumed to grant access.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param string        $type   If set, filter by object type (classname).
     *
     * @return ObjectIdentity[]
     */
    public function findObjectIdentitiesForUser(UserInterface $user, $type=null)
    {
        $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);
        $identifier = sprintf(
            '%s-%s'
                , $securityIdentity->getClass()
                , $securityIdentity->getUsername()
        );

        $sql = <<<END
SELECT
          o.object_identifier
        , c.class_type
    FROM
        {$this->options['sid_table_name']} s
    LEFT JOIN
        {$this->options['entry_table_name']} e
            ON (
                    (e.security_identity_id = s.id)
                or  {$this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getIsNullExpression('e.security_identity_id')}
            )
    LEFT JOIN
        {$this->options['oid_table_name']} o
            ON (o.id = e.object_identity_id)
    LEFT JOIN
        {$this->options['class_table_name']} c
            ON (c.id = o.class_id)
    WHERE
            s.identifier = {$this->connection->quote($identifier)}
END;

        if($type)
        {
            $sql .= <<<END
        AND c.class_type = {$this->connection->quote($type)}
END;
        }

        $objectIdentities = array();

        /* @kludge It would be awesome if we could use hydrateObjectIdentities()
         *  here.  Then we could do super fancy stuff like filter by mask and
         *  check whether ACEs grant or deny access.
         *
         * Unfortunately, that method is not accessible to subclasses.
         */
        foreach($this->connection->executeQuery($sql)->fetchAll() as $row)
        {
            $objectIdentities[] = new ObjectIdentity(
                  $row['object_identifier']
                , $row['class_type']
            );
        }

        return $objectIdentities;
    }
```

You will also need to override the ACL provider in the service container by adding the following to your bundle's `services.yml` file:

```
parameters:
  security.acl.dbal.provider.class:
    Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authorization\Acl\AclProvider
```

Then you can invoke the method e.g., in a controller like this:

```
use Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authorization\Acl\AclProvider;

/** @var AclProvider $aclProvider */
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentities = $aclProvider->findObjectIdentitiesForUser($user, $type);
```